# Struct inside struct: 'Illegal reference to non-static member' error

Tags: c++, struct, constructor

I need to create a struct inside struct. How to code the constructor correctly? Do I need to create two constructors separately for A and B or can I use only one 'outside' constructor for A like in example below? My attempts resulted in C2597 error.

```cpp
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        unsigned n;
        int* d;
    };

    A(unsigned c)
    {
        B::n = c; // C2597
        B::d = new int[c]; // C2597
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need either to make members of `B` static (but in this case you will have one value for whole program or dll in case of Windows):

```
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        static unsigned n;
        static int* d;
    };

    A(unsigned c)
    {
        B::n = c;
        B::d = new int[c];
    }
};
```

or create an instance of the `B`:

```
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        unsigned n;
        int* d;
    };

    A(unsigned c)
    {
        B b;
        b.n = c;
        b.d = new int[c];
    }
};
```

If you meant `A` to contain `B` - that is what you need to do:

```
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        unsigned n;
        int* d;
    } b;

    A(unsigned c)
    {
        b.n = c;
        b.d = new int[c];
    }
};
```

Comment: static would also mean you can only have one instance of `A` in your program otherwise you will leak memory.

Answer (score 3):

You need an *instance* of `B` in order to access the members `n` and `d`.

```
struct B
{
    unsigned n;
    int* d;
} b; // Create an instance of `B`

A(unsigned c)
{
    b.n = c;
    b.d = new int[c]; // ToDo - you need to release this memory, perhaps in ~B()
}
```

Either that or make them `static`.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't declare a member, in your code B is a nested class of class A.

You have to declare a member of that class.

```
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        unsigned n;
        int* d;
    }; // this is a class-type declaration

    B data; // this is member of class A having type of class B

    A(unsigned c) 
    {
        data.n = c; 
        data.d = new int[c]; 
    }
};
```